# Symfony not displaying default controller

Tags: php, symfony, web

so sensio labs has this example: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_controller.html

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/hello/{name}", name="hello")
     */
    public function helloAction($name)
    {
        return $this->render('default/hello.html.twig', array(
            'name' => $name
        ));
    }
}
```

I want to do something similar here's what mine looks like.

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route ("/", name ="home page")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
      return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

but when I load up the page it does not work http://sfsuse.com/~sp17g01/sp17g01/web/

the index.html.twig file is where it should be.

Comment: Since the default app.php uses the prod configuration, you'll need to make sure your clear the cache first, but either running `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` first from the project root, or clearing out the cache directory manually by doing `rm -rf var/cache` from the project root. Alternatively you can access it by doing http://sfsuse.com/~sp17g01/sp17g01/web/app_dev.php/hello/danny however you'll need to update the security rules to allow access from your IP on that file.

Comment: Thank you! for the fast answer, yes that was the problem, how do I mark it as the answer?

Comment: It's ok, I just commented, so no answer to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since the default app.php uses the prod configuration, you'll need to make sure your clear the cache first, but either running php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod first from the project root, or clearing out the cache directory manually by doing rm -rf var/cache from the project root. Alternatively you can access it by doing sfsuse.com/~sp17g01/sp17g01/web/app_dev.php/hello/danny however you'll need to update the security rules to allow access from your IP on that file

**Augwa**